# Kafka Streams windowedBy not returning after the specified time

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, delay

My requirement is to group list of messages which comes into my kafka topic having similar key to be grouped and this grouping has to happen with the window time of 5 secs. So my application should return the grouped elements after every 5secs. Below is the application which i have written. But the problem with the below code is its not returning the group of events after 5 secs its returning after 5 secs but its returning very late like 15 secs or 30 secs or more randomly.

```
KStream<String, String> source = builder
    .stream(sourceTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
    .filter((key, value) -> Objects.nonNull(value));

final KTable<Windowed<String>, List<String>> aggTable = source
    .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(String.class, objectMapper)))
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))))
    .aggregate(List<String>::new, (key, value, aggregater) -> {
        aggregater.add(value);

        return aggregater;
    },
    Materialized.<String, List<String>, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("stateStore")
            .withValueSerde(newStatusEventHolderJsonSerde()));
```

Can you please let us know do we need to do any extra coding to make stream return immediately after the specified timeout.